# Difference between anti-symmetry and transitivity in the image

Tags: logic, graph-theory, computer-science, order-theory, equivalence-relations

Attached is an image [image: programming hierarchy] I found on a joke Reddit post. In a subsequent conversation I had with a friend about the image he made a comment and I replied something to the effect "let's just assume it's a partial ordering".

Well. It's not a partial ordering for certain because it is not anti-symmetric.  Visual Basic > FORTRAN and FORTRAN > Visual Basic.

Is it transitive however? JavaScript is > visual basic > FORTRAN but FORTRAN > visual basic. What's a good example of a non-transitive anti-symmetric relation? I feel like this is really basic stuff but it's been a long time since I've sat in a mathematical logic class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for a "partial order" that's not anti-symmetric is a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder). That is, a preorder is a reflexive, transitive binary relation. If you take the arrows literally, then it is not a preorder because it is not transitive, but the intent is that you take the transitive closure of the relations indicated by the arrows. That is to say, to explicitly represent the transitive closure, you should have an arrow from "Perl programmers" to "PHP programmers" for example, among many others, but the idea is that arrow is implied.

That said, it is still not a preorder because it is not reflexive. Often when we have such diagrams we also consider self-loops implied and thus would take the reflexive-transitive closure of the relation represented by the arrows, but in this case, the meaning of the relation suggests that it is not reflexive. That is, Perl programmers don't consider themselves superior to other Perl programmers, for example. (If you *do* want to take it as each group considers itself superior to itself, then the implied relation would be a preorder.) Some cases of this do happen, i.e. whenever there's a cycle, e.g. Assembler programmers consider themselves superior to Assembler programmers. If you want to disallow this, then we can't view the diagram as implicitly specifying a transitive relation.

I'm not really sure why you ask about a non-transitive anti-symmetric relation as you seem to believe (correctly) that the diagram represents a transitive non-anti-symmetric relation. At any rate, a somewhat "everyday" example would be a relation, $R$, on people such that for people $x$ and $y$, $R(x,y)$ if and only if $y = x$ or $y$ is a child of $x$. This is anti-symmetric since no one is a child of their children, so if $R(x,y)$ holds then $R(y,x)$ can only hold if $y=x$. It's not transitive because your children's children are not your children.

Comment: Is it transitive despite the fact JavaScript feels superior to visual basic feels superior to fortran. When fortran feels superior to visual basic and it is not explicitly stated that JavaScript feels superior to fortran? Also note similar elevation of the elements doesn't define equivalency, arrow heads imply superiority. Sorry if I missed your point though! Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok after looking into your comments on reflexivity I believe maybe you thought "feeling superior to" was an equivalency, but no, all elements can be considered reflexive in that they feel equivalent to themselves. We can also assume they feel inferior to those who feel superior to them and that they feel superior to the specified groups. The real life example is awesome btw

Comment: As I said in the first paragraph, the relationship explicitly indicated by the arrows alone is not transitive. If you only consider that relation then you would presumably feel that it doesn't suggest that JavaScript programmers feel superior to Ada programmers, say. If you do think that relationship is implied, then the most natural thing to do is view the explicitly represented relationship as summarizing the transitive closure which is transitive by definition. It up to you which interpretation, if either, you take.

Comment: As to your second comment, I'm explicitly stating that (in my opinion) the relation "feels superior to" is *not* reflexive, and thus certainly not an "equivalency". Would you describe yourself as superior to your peers? If you want to interpret "feels superior to" as "feels superior or equivalent to", then presumably it would be reflexive by definition. Again, it is up to you how you want to interpret it. You'll have to ask the creator of the diagram what they had in mind if you want to know the "correct" interpretation.

Comment: Thanks so much I feel like I understand the issue now. I was firstly assuming transitivity and secondly the relation is inherently non-reflexive. I'm just a lowly computer scientist have pity on me math people! Thanks so much Derick for clearing this up. Sorry I wasted your time. In my defense it is very late at night and these are the things I lose sleep over. Have a great day/night/etc!

Answer (score 1):

a relation R is antisymmetric provided that if (x,y) in R and (y,x) in R then x=y.
a relation is transitive, on the other hand, if for every ordered pairs (x,y) and (y,z) in the relation, (x,z) is also in the relation

Comment: Yes I read the definition. So then we are in agreement that the ordering is not anti-symmetric because (x,y) and (y,x) in the relation and the two are defined in the relation a non equivalency. I also interpert this as meaning the relation is not transitive because (a,x), (x,y) (y,x) are in the relationship but no (a,y). So I suppose if I defined that JavaScript feels superior to FORTRAN it would be transitive but not anti-symmetric? This is the question I asked in the first place really.

Comment: Actually, after rereading, it's sort of the opposite but it touches on the same distinction nonetheless.

Comment: I don't think there is a way you can argue that it is the opposite, the relation types are simply different, they do not imply anything about the other.

Comment: I mean opposite in that the truth value of the two properties I originally asked about have been flipped (I asked for a non-transitive anti-symmetric relation and he provided a transitive non-antisymymetric example) but no the relations themselves are clearly just independent properties.